# What happens to matter when in a thermodynamic equilibrium?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, equilibrium

I am trying to gain a better understanding of thermodynamic equilibrium. Here's what (I think) I know:

If a system is in Thermal, Radiative, Chemical, and Mechanical Equilibrium, then it is in thermodynamic equilibrium.
When in this state, the system can do no work as there is no available free energy to use. And when a system is in this state it is at its maximum entropy.

**Please correct me if any of that is incorrect.**

What I want to know is what would something look like if it was in thermodynamic equilibrium?
Say a bit of matter like a rock was hypothetically in this state, **would it still be a rock, but with uniform heat throughout, no net force, no net radiation and no net reaction?** Or **would it have changed state to become a gas?** (because the entropy of gas is higher than that of a solid)
Or **would the rock just be heat energy?** (I say this because the Heat Death of the universe suggests that everything would just be heat energy, no matter, and in thermodynamic equilibrium)

Any of your help on any of these questions would be **extremely** useful.

Thank you.

Comment: *everything would just be heat energy, no matter* is a misconception - energy is a *property* of *physical stuff*, and not a form of stuff itself (here, classical stuff would mean matter and *physical* fields - electromagnetism and gravity - and ultimately of course just quantum fields)

Comment: Ok thank you that was very helpful. So say for instance the Earth entered thermodynamic equilibrium, would it just become a rock unable to support life or any process due to all its energy being converted into heat?

Comment: @Christoph: According to Einsteins mass energy relation, mass and energy are inter-convertible, then won't it suggest the possibility of everything to be heat energy with no matter.

Comment: @VINAY: mass is another property of stuff, and when you convert mass into energy, you convert stuff into other stuff; while total energy needs to be conserved, mass doesn't; even if you get rid of matter (assuming you mean by that 'stuff with mass'), you will still need 'stuff without mass' (in particular photons) that carries the energy

Comment: @Christoph: I think the "stuff" what you are calling has got no proper significance yet.

Comment: @VINAY: if you talk about mass or energy, you need something physically 'real' (ultimately quantum fields) that has these properties; interestingly, vacuum is a 'something' rather than a 'nothing' and can carry energy according to both quantum mechanics and general relativity (but we don't know how to make these approaches fit yet); you cannot just dump energy into the vacuum, though, as particles will start popping out; anyway, there's no such thing as pure (heat) energy; you can have a photon gas in thermal equilibrium, but that's not just energy - that's a photon gas that carries energy

Comment: @Christoph: I think energy need not have anything (matter) which carries it (like photon carrying heat, what you said). What would you like to say about kinetic energy, would you like to associate any matter particle like photon which carries  it? No. So, we can expect purely energy to exist.

Answer (score -1):

If the system is in thermal equilibrium, EVERYTHING in the system is at exactly the same Temperature;  EVERYTHING .

Otherwise it is NOT in thermal equilibrium.